# Время выполнения функций

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime, constexpr

Вот, я создал `constexpr` функцию. Как точно определить, выполнится она во время компиляции или в runtime?

Comment: Контекст использования можете добавить в вопрос?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Присвойте ее значение переменной, объявленной как `constexpr`. Если все пройдет успешно - значит, выполнилось во время компиляции :)

Comment: А если функция возвращает `void`?

Comment: а смысл в такой функции? у constexpr как бы особо и нет больше вариантов, как возвратить результат.

Comment: да можно конечно, но весь смысл в подобных функциях теряется...

Answer (score 7):

Можно попробовать использовать её в контексте, предполагающем исключительно compile-time выполнение. Например, `static_assert`:

```
constexpr void f(int a) { }
/*const*/ int i = 42;
static_assert( (f(i),true), "");
```

Без `const` у `i` будет ошибка:

> error: non-constant condition for static assertion